# WebView plugin not installed Ionic 4 app even when i have installed it

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am trying to display and uplaod images in my application. However every-time I attempt to add an image on my device i get the error

Native: tried calling WebView.convertFileSrc, but the WebView plugin is not installed."

> [ng] [console.warn]: "Install the WebView plugin: 'ionic cordova
>   plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview'

even though i have already installed the plugin.

Comment: did you add `--save ` at the time of installation

Comment: No i have just followed the guide in ionic docs installing -                                                   ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
npm install @ionic-native/ionic-webview

Comment: you should be using `npm install @ionic-native/ionic-webview --save` instead

Comment: Thanks. Im a beginner here can you explain what the difference is?

Comment: adding `--save`  flag make sure that the package.json has a  entry of the package that you install  , from latest version of npm (or above version 5) you can just use `npm i @ionic-native/ionic-webview ` instead

Comment: Thank you i will try that and see if it helps

Comment: Still not working unfortunately. Getting the same error